# Determine a subset of random variables that are most correlated with the whole

Tags: correlation, pca, optimization

I have an index variable that is calculated as the sum of $N$ random variables:

$Y = \sum_{i=1}^N x_i$.

I would like to come up with a subset, $\mathcal{S}$, of the $x_i$ such that

$Z \equiv \sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}} x_i$

is as highly correlated with $Y$ as possible. More specifically, I would like to be able to either (a) choose the cardinality of $\mathcal{S}$ and determine the highest possible correlation between $Y$ and $Z$; or (b) choose a desired correlation, and determine how big the set must be. (I don't mean to do this theoretically for a general case; I have data and I'm just interested in finding the subset of variables for the particular variables I have.)

If $N$ was small, I could do this with brute force: just calculate all possible subsets and correlations. Alas, in my setting, $N$ is about 4000.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to solve this. I wouldn't be surprised if it's been solved in some other setting, but I don't know where. It sounds somewhat related to principal component analysis, so I wouldn't be surprised if the solution involves using eigenvectors.

Answer (score 6):

This is a discrete optimization problem, and eigenvalues will be of little help. PCA solves an optimization problem that is quadratic in its arguments, and that's the reason eigenvalues are relevant for it. You can

1. Entertain a greedy search: at step $k$, include into $S$ the variable $X_k$ that has the highest partial correlation with $Y$ given the variables already in $S$
2. Entertain [the simplex method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) or some other linear programming method that steps between the vertices of the unit cube, interpreting $Z=\sum_i a_i x_i$, $a_i=1$ if $i\in S$, and $0$ otherwise, and optimizing over $a_i$.
3. Entertain [the branch and bound method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound), although with 4000 entries, it is probably hopeless.
4. Entertain ad hoc stochastic optimization methods, such as [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) or [genetic algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm).

I tried working out a similar problem of finding the best subscale for Cronbach's alpha, but have not found anything practical yet.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. I'll have to look into these methods.